# Formatting code in code blocks

Tags: eclipse, formatting, codeblocks

I have recently gone from java(in eclipse) to C++ in code blocks, and I was wondering if there was a way to format code in code blocks like there is in eclipse (ctrl+shift+F), if not could someone point me towards a plugin or something of the like?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278082/is-there-any-shortcut-for-codeblocks-to-fomat-the-code

Answer (score 3):

AStyle is a code formatting plugin for code blocks which allowes you to do this.

Info: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Source_Code_Formatter_plugin