# Is there any shortcut for CodeBlocks to format the code?

Tags: codeblocks, hotkeys

Is there any shortcut for CodeBlocks to format the code?

I haven't find any tip in google.

I found only "format use AStyle", but it come up with right mouse button only...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

probably not by default but you should be able to assign it there:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Keyboard shortcuts -> Plugins -> Source code formatter (AStyle)
```

[image]

Comment: in v16.01 (as of speaking, latest stable release), i can't find the Keyboard Shortcuts page :/

Comment: Still relevant for v17.12

Comment: In Ubuntu, if you didn't find the *Keyboard shortcuts* setting then install the `codeblocks-contrib` from the terminal. 
Install command: `sudo apt install codeblocks-contrib`.

Answer (score 4):

**My favourite =** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

You (these are the default settings I believe) can select a block of code and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. This will **indent** the entire block.

So for indenting a whole file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

In addition, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on a selected block to **"unindent"**

You can move through the open tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

**As for the best shortcuts:**

I like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate a line and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to copy it.

Anyway,  you can set whatever shortkeys you like in the Editor menu (there you will also be able to find all shortkey currently set).