# Is there any way to auto format ( AStyle ) while typing code in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, c, ide, codeblocks, formatter

I always format code in `Code::Blocks` using Source Code Formatter (`AStyle`) 
plugin. I need to press `short-cut` keys or  right click to mouse to apply formatting. 
Is there any better way to format code without pressing any keys or mouse clicks?
 
Thanks !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any shortcut for CodeBlocks to format the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278082/is-there-any-shortcut-for-codeblocks-to-format-the-code)